# Ruby Installation

Tags: ruby

Silly question. I went to http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/ and installed Ruby 1.9.2, but when I pull up command prompt and type `ruby -v` it's not recognized as a command. Am I doing something wrong? I had version 1.8.6 installed, but I couldn't figure out how to upgrade my Ruby version so I uninstalled it and tried a fresh install.

Comment: @Close voter: Have you read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61720/where-should-questions-about-software-development-tools-go ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add Ruby to your path variable, regardless of your operating system.

Say you're using Windows, and Ruby is installed in `C:\Program Files\ruby1.9.2\` You'll need to find out which folder the ruby executable is in (`ruby.exe`). Sometimes it'll be in the main folder, but usually for open source packages it'll be in the subfolder `bin`. To add ruby to your path, then, you'll need to use `C:\Program Files\ruby1.9.1\bin`

You can do this on the command line like so:

`path = %PATH%;C:\Program Files\ruby1.9.2\bin`

Note that `%PATH%` has a percent sign on either side, and that there's a semi-colon separating it from the new value. You'll have to type it in each time you start a new command line window, but it might be a good idea to try this the first time, because any mistakes in typing it in won't be permanent.

To change it permanently you can find it in `Control Panel` > `System` > `Advanced System Settings`. Switch to the `Advanced` tab, then click `Environment Variables...` Find `path` under System Variables, and add `;C:\Program Files\ruby1.9.2\bin` to the end. Note that you still need a semi-colon to separate the new value from everything else, and that you don't need `%PATH%` this time (in face, the value you see is what `%PATH%` represents). Once you've done that, restart any command windows you had open, and you should be able to access things just fine!

These instructions will be different if you're using Linux or a Mac - try googling environment variables if you'd like to know more!

Comment: It worked. I set the path in the environment variables. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Did you add your bin Directory to the PATH?

Ok, when you install it, it will go in a directory:

ex: c:/program files/ruby1.9.x/

inside you will have a /bin directory which contains all the command for the command line.

To be able to use ruby in the command line, you must add it to your $PATH variable in the OS environment.
ex:
path=c:/program files/ruby1.9.x/bin;etc...

Comment: Not sure what you mean, so no I haven't.

Comment: if you are in windows you have to modify your env. variables.  see edited response.

Comment: Quick note: the path variable for Windows is %PATH%, not $PATH like in Linux.

Comment: @Hannele good point, i'm on MAC and i was writting this from memory... which fail me sometime ;-)

Answer (score 0):

***Install RVM with RUBY***

> **sudo apt-get install curl**

after install
install rvm also ruby

> **\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby**

if you face issue with the above line (Failed to connect to get.rvm.io port 443: Network is unreachable)

in browser go to **https://get.rvm.io** save the page in any location

> **make it executable** file name rvm-installer
>
> **chmod +x rvm-installer**
>
> then do the following
>
> **bash rvm-installer stable --ruby**
>
> source /home/username/.rvm/scripts/rvm

then check **rvm list**

note the version of ruby listing on terminal

---

if you failed to install due to the dependency

**sudo apt-get update**

**sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev**

if the above steps not installed ruby latest version you can do it by
**rvm install ruby-2.1.1**

> installation using rvm
>
> sudo apt-get install libgdbm-dev libncurses5-dev automake libtool bison libffi-dev
>
> curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
>
> source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
>
> echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bashrc
>
> rvm install 2.1.1
>
> rvm use 2.1.1 --default ruby -v

---

**change terminal to login shell. open a new terminal **

then **rvm use 2.1.1**   => ( 2.1.1 version )

then its done!

pd@admin:~$ **ruby -v**

ruby 2.1.1p76 (2014-02-24 revision 45161) [x86_64-linux]

programmers keep on coding with ruby.